# Resampling to subset (jackknife) or bootstrap for survival analysis

Tags: survival, bootstrap, jackknife

This is a question regarding survival analysis and bootstrap: Suppose I have a time-to-event dataset with 1000 subjects, and based on this dataset I can obtain some measures or plots (not standard, o.w. there will be analytical formulas to calculate and quantify the uncertainty). The bootstrap is the first idea that comes to my mind in order to get many replicates and repeat the same process. However, there are two choices (maybe more):

- I resample **with** replacement for the 1000 subjects to get each bootstrap dataset (size of 1000), and then use each bootstrap dataset for the same analysis
- I resample **without** replacement for 90% of the 1000 subjects to get each jackknife dataset (I assume the "delete-m" case where m=100 here is a type of jackknife), and then use each jackknife dataset for the same analysis.

The algorithm I applied to each resampled dataset (bootstrap or jackknife) seems to get more consistent results for jackknife datasets. I don't know if approximately 37% samples appearing more than once in the bootstrapping will have some (negative) impact. I appreciate if some publications are there for similar discussions.

Comment: Did you account for the jackknife multipliers properly?

Comment: @StasK thanks for your reply - can you plz be more specific on jackknife multiplier? any literature discussing the impact of it? thanks

Comment: It's something like $(n-m)/m$ that needs to go in front of the difference to produce a pseudo-value that's on such a scale that taking an empirical variance of these pseudo-values produces the correct variance estimate. [Shao and Tu](http://www.amazon.com/Jackknife-Bootstrap-Springer-Series-Statistics/dp/0387945156) must have it.